# Downloading updates bypassing the Appstore

Tags: macos, mac, applications, mac-appstore, big-sur

I’m looking download and store offline an update for Mac OS Monterey 12.3.1 in order to install it on 30 Macbooks in the future. The store doesn’t list dot versions or pre-release versions.

Is it possible to download a specific update for mac os bypassing the appstore?

Comment: OS updates for minor version aren't through the AppStore. What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: How to download the offline update for mac Mac OS Monterey 12.5.3 in order to install it on 30 Macbooks in the future.

Comment: Just download it on one Mac and save the installer app before installing it.

Comment: You can set one Mac to be content server for the others

Comment: 12.5.3 doesn't exist publicly, but I'll show how to get to available updates in an answer. This is a very good thing to have, even if you use content caching. Many people I know catalog all the updates, just in case for large deployments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go basic and command line to download the full installer.

```
softwareupdate -d --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 12.3.1
```

You can use a tool that reads the catalog for all available versions:

- https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/mac-deploy-stick/ (skip the certificate part and clock the bottom left items in the main window)
- https://github.com/munki/macadmin-scripts/blob/main/installinstallmacos.py (amazing python all in one tool)
- https://github.com/ninxsoft/Mist (great app, has command line tool, does exactly what you ask )

[image]

Comment: n.b. I chose 12.3.1 in the fetch full installer example to fail since that version is no longer available. We can edit this if the OP needs a version and doesn't use the other tools that list the catalog